# Issues with installing packages with custom shell script on WSL

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm setting up a WSL installation with Ubuntu 18.04 on my Windows 10 computer. What I'm trying to accomplish is having a shell script which installs all my packages, configs among others- on my Ubuntu instance (Node, Yarn, Git-flow, etc.). It seems like the only command running from my shell script is the `sudo apt-get update`, as I'm actually getting feedback from this in the console (see code posted below). All of the other scripts/commands are failing or giving an error. I'm quite new to writing shell scripts, so it might be something crucial that I'm overlooking.

What I have done thus far is installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 18.04. Created a new user and a password. Thereafter, created a `symlink` to my folder windows **D:** drive, where I wish to store all my development projects.

Symlink: `ln -s /mnt/d/development`. This now appears as `@Development -> /mnt/d/Development` in my WSL root `~`.

Weirdly, when I'm trying to install or search for packages with `sudo apt-get git-flow` or `sudo apt search git-glow` I can both find it and install it as expected.

**Note:** This is a fresh new install of Ubuntu 18.04, and I have not configured or touched any other files in `/env` or other system files.

I have mostly followed other "starter" examples on setting up a shell script for Ubuntu on WSL. But unfortunately leads to the same issue/problem mentioned above. I have a `wsl_setup.sh` file which is located at `D:\wsl_setup.sh` on my Windows drive. What I'm trying to do is open the Ubuntu terminal and from the root (user) execute the script; `martin@Windows-PC: ~$ sh /mnt/d/wsl_setup.sh`.

This is a minified version of the shell script, which still fails.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Download the updated package list for your installed repositories and dependencies to their newest version.
sudo apt-get update
# Installing Git
sudo apt-get install git
# Install git-flow AVH
sudo apt-get install git-flow
```

In a perfect world, I would like to have this shell script execute all my package installs instead of manually doing this in the Ubuntu terminal. One of the use-cases, why I'm trying to accomplish this, would be if I needed to reformat or install WSL, I could just run this script and be back up and running in no time.

The error/issue I'm getting when I'm running the script mentioned above is the following:

```
E: Invalid operation update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git-flow
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems with apt-get update, check its output. Sometimes the repositories are down; you'll need to check later. Also, check your internet connection. Here an improvement to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Download the updated package list for your installed repositories and dependencies to their newest version.
sudo apt-get update
# Installing Git
sudo apt-get -y -q install git
# Install git-flow AVH
sudo apt-get -y -q install git-flow
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Carlos. I think the issue you are relating to might have been because some of the packages might already have been installed on the system. I have continued upgrading, debugging and installed a fresh Ubuntu instance and it seems to come together slowly. I will update the post with the new shell script when I get it working. 

**Note:** There might be a million reasons why I received these errors posted above, but as I'm new to writing these kinds of scripts, it's hard to know exactly what prompted them. Sorry about that. Learning as I go. Thanks again.